# How to add "active" class to navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sails.js

I am following the "SailsCasts" and I would like to figure out how to set .ejs template from the class "active" in my navbar according to the link that I'm browsing.

I do not want to use the "title" of the page as well as imagined is quite weak. Nor do I want to use JavaScript on the client side. I would like the class "active" in the navbar Bootstrap was written directly on the server side depending on the page I'm visiting.

A parameter to be passed through the routes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set HTML element's class in your EJS file depending on current controller and action. This information is stored in variable called **req.options** exposed in all views.

You can access use it in the following way:

*/views/navigation.ejs*

```
<ul>
    <li class="<%- (req.options.controller === 'someController' && req.options.action === 'someAction') ? 'active' : ''%>">User list</li>
</ul>
```

If you're going to use this method multiple times, you should create a global service:

*/api/services/Helper.js*

```
module.exports = {
  isCurrentPage: function(req, controller, action) {
    return (req.options.controller === controller && req.options.action === action)
  }
}
```

then, in your ejs view:

*/views/navigation.ejs*

```
<ul>
    <li class="<%= Helper.isCurrentPage(req, 'users', 'list') ? 'active' : ''%>">User list</li>
</ul>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't work. I have a controller `UserController.js` and I write === user but I have an error: `user is not defined]`. If I write `User` then I not have the error but nothing appear. The same if I put or leave ` && action etc...`. how to fix?

Comment: Variable on the right hand side of the comparison operator must be a string.
For example:
<%= (req.options.controller === 'user') ? 'active' : '' %>

Comment: Excuse me, @abeja, but the Helper.js doesn't work. It says error: req is not defined]. How to?

Comment: @ginolon Sorry, I forgot to add 'req' parameter to the function definition. I've just fixed the answer - should work now.